# Click Button To Do two things And Vice Versa

Tags: android, android-studio, button

I want to make button which will call two function on click I am using this code currently but when I click it on 3rd time nothing happens and I want to do vice versa like when user click on button 3rd time it will call count 1 again.. this code is currently I am using

```java
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    clickcount=clickcount+1;

    if(clickcount==1)
    {
        Random i = new Random ();
        int c= i.nextInt(7-1) + 1;
        bck.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        TextView textresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textresult.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    else
    {
        Random i = new Random ();
        int c= i.nextInt(7-1) + 1;
        bck.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        TextView textresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textresult.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
}
```

Comment: assign clickcount=0; again in else part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello mate Please do like this

```java
clickcount=0;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    clickcount = clickcount + 1;
    if(clickcount%2 == 1) {
        Random i = new Random ();
        int c = i.nextInt(7 - 1) + 1;
        bck.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        TextView textresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textresult.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    } else {
        Random i = new Random ();
        int c = i.nextInt(7 - 1) + 1;
        bck.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        TextView textresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textresult.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with boolean:

```
boolean check = true;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Random i = new Random ();
    TextView textresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    int c= i.nextInt(7-1) + 1;

    bck.setBackgroundColor(check ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
    textresult.setTextColor(check ? Color.WHITE : Color.BLACK);

    check = !check;
}
```

Or if you want two functions:

```
boolean check = true;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(check) {
      // first function
    } else {
      // second function
    }
    check = !check;
}
```